# Is it necessary to implement iterable for a generic array based buffer?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

I learned that one of the reasons behind creating a generic data-structure is to make  life simple for the client who'll be using it. So , as a part of that package , one should also make his/her data-structure implement iterable so that itcan be easily iterated over using a `for-each()` loop.

I created a generic resizing circular array based buffer. Now , since array is already iterable , do i need to implement an iterable ?

**Edit:** @Sotirios Delimanolis , this is what i came up with :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class ResizingCircularArray<E> {

    private int head = 0;
    private int tail = 0;
    private int size = 0; // a measure of non-null elements in the array
    private E[] arr;

    private void resize() {
        System.out.println("resizing array to size: " + 2 * size);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E[] tempArr = (E[]) new Object[2 * size];
        System.arraycopy(arr, head, tempArr, 0, size);
        head = 0;
        tail = head + (size - 1);
        arr = tempArr;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ResizingCircularArray() {
        arr = (E[]) new Object[5];
    }

    public void enqueue(E item) {
        if (item == null)
            throw new java.lang.NullPointerException(
                    " adding null values is not allowed ");
        if (size == arr.length) {
            resize();
        }
        arr[tail++] = item;
        size++;
        System.out.println("head : " + head + " tail : " + tail + " , size : "
                + size);
    }

    public E dequeue() {
        if (size == 0)
            throw new java.lang.NullPointerException("size = 0");
        if (size == arr.length / 4) {
            resize();
        }
        E item = arr[head];
        arr[head++] = null;
        size--;
        System.out.println("head : " + head + " tail : " + tail + " , size : "
                + size);
        return item;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public E sample(int offset) {
        if (offset < 0)
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException(
                    "negative index not allowed");
        return arr[head + offset];
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void display() {
        for (E item : arr)
            System.out.print(item + " ");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ResizingCircularArray<String> r = new ResizingCircularArray<String>();
        String line = null;
        String[] segment, parsed;
        boolean endFlag = false;

        try (BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "CircArrayPoints.txt"))) {
            line = is.readLine();
            segment = line.trim().split(";");
            for (int i = 0; !segment[i].equals("stop") && !endFlag; i++) {
                parsed = segment[i].split(" ");
                switch (parsed[0]) {
                case "enq":
                    System.out.println("adding : " + parsed[1]);
                    r.enqueue(parsed[1]);
                    r.display();
                    break;
                case "deq":
                    System.out.println("dequeing : " + r.sample(0));
                    if (r.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Empty queue");
                        endFlag = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    r.dequeue();
                    r.display();
                    break;
                case "disp":
                    r.display();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Files : CircArrayPoints.txt**

```
enq a;enq b;enq c;enq d;enq e;enq f;enq g;enq h;enq i;enq j;enq k;enq l;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;deq;disp;stop
```

Comment: _Now , since array is already iterable , do i need to implement an iterable ?_ Explain that with code. It doesn't matter if your underlying data structure is iterable. It's your top level structure you want to iterate over.

Comment: Maybe. Instead of asking strangers on the Internet, ask those who will be using the data structure. Would it make their lives easier if the data structure were iterable?

Comment: Your data structure sounds suspiciously similar to [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html). You might want to check if that built-in class does what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be exposing the internal array to your users, so yes, you should make your wrapper object iterable.

Also, Arrays aren't `Iterable`s—`javac` just knows how to handle both `Iterable` objects and Arrays in for-each loops. This might make it look like Arrays are `Iterable`, but it's actually just a special case the compiler handles.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out , i spoke of `iterable` a bit too loosely perhaps. I'm using a private array , So its not exposed. Trying to follow the rules as much as possible. I'll edit the post to include my code as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to, but you can *choose* to.

Ask those who will be using your data structure. Would it make their lives easier if the data structure were iterable?

Comment: Yeah , would have been great if people were really implementing my code. But I'm a student , and the only ones implementing my code is me. hence the post.